# Django rest framework, JWT and request.session

Tags: django, session, session-variables, django-rest-framework, jwt

I use Django rest framework with JWT for authentication and everything works perfectly BUT...
I need to save an information about the user in a session var at login and I really don't know where I can do the request.session['mydata'] = plop

I tried :

```
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
  serializedUser = UserSerializer(user).data
  request.session['mydata'] = serializedUser.mydata
  return {
    'token': token,
    'user': serializedUser
  }
```

But it doesn't work...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.session` is managed through [Django's session framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/) which requires the use of session cookies and is what powers `SessionAuthentication`.

JWT is completely separate from session authentication, and does not provide a way to store arbitrary data on the token.

Comment: so if all my data depend of an "office_id" in the user table, with JWT I have to request my user table before each other request ?

Comment: I believe JWT carries a reference to the `User` already, but yes you would have to.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    return {
        'token': token,
        'user': UserSerializer(
            user,
            context={
                'request': request
            },
        ).data
    }
```

Whatever fields you add to your UserSerializer will be included in the response along with the token.

You can then use that to store the information in localstorage along with the token so that it's available to your SPA without having to make a separate call each time.

The only difference from the docs is the addition of `context={'request': request},` which is probably a result of a change in the DRF since the JWT docs were written.