# Error overriding jwt_response_payload_handler to add serialized user

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

***Following the comment in this function, I've added a call to UserSerializer.  But I seem to be missing something that's not covered here, because I get an error.***

```
# settings
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=36000),
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'base.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',
}

# serializers
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')

# utils
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    """
    Returns the response data for both the login and refresh views.
    Override to return a custom response such as including the
    serialized representation of the User.
    """

    return {
        'token': token,
        'user': UserSerializer(user).data
    }
```

***Use Postman to POST to http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/ with:***

```
{"username":"admin","password":"password123"}
```

***Resulting Error:***

```
AssertionError: `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the
serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating
the serializer. // Werkzeug Debugger
```

***Change and POST again:***

```
return {
    'token': token,
    'user': UserSerializer(context={
      'request': request, 
      'user': user
    }).data
}
```

***Result is no error, but user is empty.***

```
{
  "user": {
    "username": "",
    "email": "",
    "groups": []
  },
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NjA1MjU5MDgsInVzZXJfaWQiOjEsImVtYWlsIjoiYWRtaW5AYWxrLmNvbSIsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiYWRtaW4ifQ.GLTtlFk2akZIgNb4lGULhyKbgPML1IgYG5lEsfsCoaU"
}
```

***Just to prove that the issue is with how I'm trying to use the Serializer, I tried:***

```
return {
    'token': token,
    'user': user.pk # Does the user instance contain anything?
    # 'user': UserSerializer(context={'user': user}).data
}
```

***And got:***

```
{
  "user": 1, # yes
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBhbGsuY29tIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MSwiZXhwIjoxNDYwNTI2MDc4fQ.HFOGQCM-PkBIJhWZWoD255ku719AA5n70ohcFGFhHT0"
}
```

***What am I missing?***

- [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546704/django-rest-framework-jwt-and-request-session) looks like the user was after the same solution, but didn't offer the "What doesn't work exactly" details, which I have done in my question.  The accepted answer  also doesn't provide a solution, just a response of "You have to do it some other way" *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Through the magic of obsessing over writing a quality question, I found the missing syntactic detail!**

The user instance and context needed to be sent in that order instead of the user being included in the context.

```
return {
    'token': token,
    'user': UserSerializer(user,context={'request': request},).data
}
```

The reason in my case was because I was subclassing a HyperlinkedModelSerializer for the UserSerialize.  This requires the request context so it can generate fully qualified URLs.

[See Docs.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)